# My 18 month daughter wants to leave the apartment all the time

Tags: toddler, outdoor, hyperactiveness

My wife is a homemaker and my daughter stays with her in the home. They go shopping 2 times a week. Everyday after work I take her out into the building/balcony/street for 30-40 minutes. She usually get's ready to jump outside the moment she sees me. Then she we come home and everything is OK.

Problem is when we have friends at our home or go to friends house she cries like almost no end to get out of the house and wants to stay outside for ALL the time. She just started to be like this in the past month. Before that she was just hyperactive indoors.

It doesn't matter if it's 4 people extra or 15 people with kids. She just goes to them, holds their hand or our hands, cries and pulls them towards the apartment door/balcony.

I then usually take her outside she just runs around, barks at dogs, plays with her ball, pushes things, etc but she wants to be out for all the time not just 30-40 minutes.

Usually where the place is small she doesn't like it. If the place is very big she can withstand (that exact same group) all the other kids, noise.

Any solution or is this just a thing that will get solved by time?

Comment: I have no idea. It could be as simple as she prefers a less crowded environment or likes being outside. I don't think we have enough information to help. Children are people first and we all have individual likes and dislikes.

Comment: @WillowRex I understand but currently my options are limited to: 1. not seeing friends 2. taking her outside to play for 80-120 minutes 3. let her cry until she gets over with it, usually in a 3 hr party she cries from minute 30-45, then we go out till minute 75 then comes back in, either cries for another good 15 until I take her out again or just forgets. But again a month ago she was playing with the kids all along...

Comment: Honey, I am so sorry. It must be very difficult for you -- all of you. I simply doubt we can answer and I doubt she has enough vocabulary to tell you why she is acting this way. You and your partner could get a sitter or take turns keeping her out of a party. That she is upset and troubled seems obvious -- but I can't help with why. She could be agoraphobic, but this seems extremely unlikely and has never been diagnosed (as far as I know) in anyone this young. There are too many 'could be's and probably 'aren't's.  18 months is a  prime time for 'making strange'. They just want their own way.

Comment: I am not the only poster here. Someone may have had experience similar to this. A moderator might be able to help you write the question in a way to get you more and better answers, I hope so.

Comment: Have you considered meeting up with friends outside? Have a barbecue in a park? A picnic?

Comment: "everyday I take her out" does people not her daily caregiver almost always mean outside time? It could also be she is bored of her space.

Comment: There is a possibility of Aspergers though I am no expert. It may be that she finds social situations overwhelming. It is thought to be highly under-diagnosed in girls as they are able to mask the symptoms through copying other people.

Comment: IMO, (I have over 30 years experience in this field), no one can diagnose any challenge over the internet. I think if a parent has concerns the **only** recourse is to see a medical professional in developmental challenges. I would not diagnose even in person with all my  teaching experience, even if I had thoughts about it..

Comment: Thus the reason I said that I'm no expert and also that there's a possibility. but sometimes a hint in a direction can inspire someone to look in a direction that may otherwise be missed and seek professional help.

Comment: I think your downvote was because site policy suggests we do not place fears into the mix. Also why Asperger's? -- there are dozens of possibilities if we are going to extremes. I am not looking for an answer. This site has been difficult for me because I did the same as you -- made a suggestion based on a possibility. So welcome, and I hope you stick around in spite of downvotes and people disagreeing with you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of nowhere, My wife came up with this idea that has so far worked for us.

When we go to a new place, or many people come to our apartment, we just keep hold her in our arms until **she wants** to leave (or I guess until she feels secure/loved enough). My daughter is hyperactive, normally she doesn't want to be carried, but it seems in a place where there's too many people she may want that first.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar situation before, my two year old daughter was crying heartily outside in public for hours and telling me she doesn't want to go back home. She can speak some phrases and sentences but communication is very laborious to understand her. But I can manage to understand her that she likes to go store nearby and she just wanted to see Mickey Mouse toys there.

1. Please be patient and try to understand why your child wants to stay outside.
2. Do talk to your child and get to know what are attractive to your child keeping outside. Is it outdoor activities your child like to continue for hours? Or is it a some outdoor place your child like to linger around? Is it a thing your child like you to buy for?
3. Does your child dislike something inside the house? For example, newly bought toys or furniture or things your child doesn't like.
4. It is highly not recommended to frighten child with some imaginary monster or real life insects or whatever children scared of inside the house. It could be someone (family member or outsiders, school friends, TV program or whatever your child has access) told her there is something inside your house (or anyone's house for your case)and it might bothering her so much. Please try to get to know what is bothering but use diplomatic way to know it. Do not try asking your child openly if ambience doesn't seem you should. I have some experience my daughter scare of spiders. I tried to show her stuffed spider toys in toys store and let her touch them and hold them. Patience, timing and mood of your child is the key. Do not use brute force and get go slowly to get timing.
5. Please get indoor atmosphere as pleasing as outdoor playgrounds and parks. There are physical limitations but sensationally it could be as close as possible. Let your child have warm, nice atmosphere inside the house.
6. Please monitor TV program and media access. Do not let people or media give poor information about house indoor. Mitigate them if something is bothering your child to be indoors. 
   Hope any of items above can tackle your problem.

Comment: Thanks 1. will do 2. just going outside and seeing new places (if you turn her around, she will turn you around in defiance and will want to continue going) 3. she only does this when it's congested 4. we don't frighten her. She's 18 months, she wouldn't even understand if we did 5. she likes indoor as long as it's not congested **she's ok with the same people** if the place is big 6. we monitor

Comment: When you mean congested, does the house have good ventilation while there are many people in the house? My concern is the word congested how congested is congested?

Comment: like an apartment of two bedrooms but with 20 people in it :D